# An elegant way to reduce code when setting up uri queryParams in Angular?

Tags: angular, query-string

I have a method that sets up an endpoint in an angular service and as there are 3 or four elements to the query param, the line is getting long.

Is there a more elegant way to set this up?

```
private endpoint = (
    var1: Type1,
    var2: Type2,
    var3: Type3
  ) => {
    let uri = `path?query1=${var1}&query2=${var2}&draft=true&query3=${var3}`;
    return uri;
  };
```

I think there should be a better way to write this, where if I require extending this further, it could be quicker? I can't find anything around which could help me online.

Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

In my case I've created a separate service to handle such stuff, for example:

```
@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class SharedHttpService {

    /**
     * Function transforms the given object's properties into a string of GET params;
     * This function will omit properties that are undefined;
     * @param criteria - object representing fields that can be undefined or not.
     */
    transformCriteria(criteria: Criteria | NonPagedCriteria): String {
        if (!criteria) {
            return '';
        }

        let criteriaString = '?';
        for (const key of Object.keys(criteria)) {
            if (criteria[key] === undefined || criteria[key] === null || criteria[key].length === 0 || key === 'sort') {
                continue;
            }
            if (criteriaString !== '?') {
                criteriaString += '&';
            }
            criteriaString += key + '=' + criteria[key];
        }
        if (criteria.sort && criteria.sort.direction) {
            const sort = {...criteria.sort};
            criteriaString += `&sort=${sort.paramName},${sort.direction}`;
        }

        return criteriaString;
    }
}
```

Note that `Criteria` and `NonPagedCriteria` are custom interfaces which are extended by the objects which are passed to the http service and are treated as a collection of params that should appear in the URL.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set params as array:

```js
endpoint = params => {
      let uri ='path?';
      params.forEach((element, ind) => {
          uri += `query${++ind}=${element}${(ind < params.length - 1) ? '&':''}`;
      });
      return uri;
  }

  console.log(endpoint(['first','second','third']))
```

or use [arguments object of function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments):

```js
function endpoint() {
    const params = arguments[0];
    let uri ='path?';
    params.forEach((element, ind) => {
        uri += `query${++ind}=${element}${(ind < params.length - 1) ? '&':''}`;
    });
    return uri;
}

console.log(endpoint(['first','second','three']))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `params` propertry of the [`options`](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpClient#request) parameter of the HTTP methods. Try the following

```js
private options = (
    var1: Type1,
    var2: Type2,
    var3: Type3
  ) => {
    return { query1: var1, query2: var2, query3: var3 } 
  };
```

You could then use it as

```js
this.http.get(this.path, { params: this.options('one', 'two', 'three') });
```